# fifth degree equation

Tags: polynomials

The general form of the fifth degree equation to achieve Bring-jerrard form some coefficients are complex . Should they be considered only real part of the coefficients that the roots of the fifth degree equation with Bring- jerrard form be equal to the numeric value?

Comment: I would guess that does not work.  You may be getting a form of "casus irreducibilis", a term usually applied to cubic equations but it happens with higher degrees too.